# pandas count groupy 2 attributes

Tags: pandas

I have a list that looks like this:

```
Name arrival_date location
Tom  2019-12-12   Hardware store
Tina 2019-12-31   Post office         
Tina 2019-12-14   Post office
Tina 2019-11-30   Police station
```

With a few thousand entries. The data goes from april 2018 to april 2020

Now I would like to count the number of arrivals for each stop for each date over 2 years
So that is basically looks like this:

```
October 2018
   Hardware Store:26
   Police Station:13
   ...
November 2019
   Hardware Store:226
   Police Station:113
   ...
```

What is a good way to do this with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counts per both attributes:

```
#if necessary
#df['arrival_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_date'])
#df = df.sort_values('arrival_date')

s = df['arrival_date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y').rename('month-year')
df = df.groupby([s, 'location'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
      month-year        location  count
0  December 2019  Hardware store      1
1  December 2019     Post office      2
2  November 2019  Police station      1
```